# Migrations creating at root folder, not migration folder

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

After trying to create migrations, migration file adding in root folder, how can I add file in src/migration folder?

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
        type: config.get<'aurora-postgres'>('TYPEORM_CONNECTION'),
        username: config.get<string>('TYPEORM_USERNAME'),
        password: config.get<string>('TYPEORM_PASSWORD'),
        database: config.get<string>('TYPEORM_DATABASE'),
        port: config.get<number>('TYPEORM_PORT'),
        entities: ['../src/entities/**/*.ts'],
        migrations: ['../src/migrations/**/*.ts'],
        cli: {
          entitiesDir: '/src/entities',
          migrationsDir: '/src/migrations',
        },
        synchronize: false,
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        logging: true,
      }),
    })
```

package.json:

```
{
"migration:create": "ts-node --transpile-only ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:create"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration passed to `TypeOrmModule.forRoot()` is not read by the typeorm`CLI. I would suggest creating a orm config file that's specific for the CLI, something like`typeorm-cli.config.js` and reference it when using the TypeORM CLI